# Simple Firebase authentication problem in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I'm only starting with Xamarin forms for cross platform app development and I'm having a problem at something that should be very simple.
Have created a basic cross platform app and installed and referenced all of the required packages for Firebase authentication. I've also created a project in the Firebase console, configured it for email and password authentication and I've registered a user, etc.
So, I've written a basic method in the Android project to check if the current user is logged in.

```
public async Task<string> GetCurrentUser()
{
    string userID = null;

    if (FirebaseAuth != null)
    {
        try
        {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.CurrentUser;
            if (user != null)
            {
                var userToken = await user.GetIdTokenAsync(false);
                userID = userToken.Token;
            }
        }
        catch (FirebaseAuthException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to get a FirebaseAuth instance");
    }

    return userID;
}
```

However, the call to user.GetIdTokenAsync(false); simply never returns.

Why?

Comment: Did you get the user from FirebaseAuth.CurrentUser? If the user is not null, that means the current user is logged in. Did you get any exception when call user.GetIdTokenAsync? You can change the FirebaseAuthException to exception to catch more exception.

Comment: user comes back not null. No exception occurs on the user.GetIdTokenAsync - I added a catch(Exception e) block and still nothing.

Comment: You add a breakpoint at the line userID and it never hitted? Are you using the latest version of those nuget packages?

Comment: Yeah, using the latest versions from nuget. Breakpoint on userID line never hit and no exceptions occurring.

Comment: @ThomasS, Found a solution for this?